# wp,sql,image in folder not showing up but in database ..it is entered

Tags: mysql, wordpress

```
$uploadDir = 'images/';
$fileName = $_FILES['Photo']['name'];
$tmpName = $_FILES['Photo']['tmp_name']; 
$fileSize = $_FILES['Photo']['size']; 
$fileType = $_FILES['Photo']['type'];
$filePath = $uploadDir . $fileName; 
$result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filePath);
```

Comment: help me out plz...file is uploaded in db,,but not showing in the "images" folder

Answer (score 0):

As [commented by Darrel](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php#52954) on the `move_uploaded_file()` manual page:

> `move_uploaded_file apparently uses the root of the Apache installation (e.g. "Apache Group\Apache2" under Windows) as the upload location if relative pathnames are used.
>
>   
>
>   For example, 
>
>   $ftmp = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
>
>   $fname = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
>
>   move_uploaded_file($ftmp, $fname);
>
>                              
>
>   moves the file to 
>
>   "Apache Group\Apache2\$fname";
>
>   
>
>   In contrast, other file/directory related functions use the current directory of the php script as the offset for relative pathnames.  So, for example, if the command
>
>   
>
>   mkdir('tmp');
>
>   
>
>   is called from 'Apache Group\Apache2\htdocs\testpages\upload.php', the result is to create
>
>   'Apache Group\Apache2\htdocs\testpages\tmp'
>
>   
>
>   On the other hand, if 'mkdir' is called just before 'move_uploaded_file', the behavior changes.  The commands, 
>
>   
>
>   mkdir('tmp');
>
>   move_uploaded_file($ftmp, $fname);
>
>   
>
>   used together result in 
>
>   
>
>   "Apache Group\Apache2\htdocs\testpages\tmp\$fname"
>
>   
>
>   being created.  Wonder if this is a bug or a feature.`

Comment: what should i do now,,guide me

Comment: problem may with the path only

Comment: @happy: Use an absolute (rather than a relative) path?

Comment: but it is giving error if i use   -1 down vote favorite
$uploadDir = 'D:\xampp\htdocs\js\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\img\images'/'; instead of $uploadDir ='images/';..string(58) "D:\xampp\htdocs\js\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\img\images"
Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: File exists in D:\xampp\htdocs\js\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\img\img.php on line 48
Successfully Submitted

Comment: string(58) "D:\xampp\htdocs\js\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\img\images" Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: File exists in D:\xampp\htdocs\js\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\img\img.php on line 48 Successfully Submitted.............this id the error now

Comment: i got it ...i got it..thank u very much..absolute path worked..jst added $uploadDir = 'D:\xampp\htdocs\js\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\img\images\ '; in place of $uploadDir='images/ '